# Ecommerce websites push notification in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Anyone tell me how flipkart send push notifications to android device?

Is flipkart work under GCM?

Any answer will help me

Comment: GCM is used by most applications running on android. What flipkart uses only flipkart engineers can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> Any answer will help me

Flipkart may have their own notfication API made by their developer team or I don't know what service they use as its confidential, **but you can use** [onesignal.com](https://onesignal.com/) , its cross platform
push notification delivery to Send Smarter Notifications

**Features:**

1. Its free for basic needs
2. Its very simple
3. You can include image in push notification

For more read their [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/)

The answer is late but Hope this helps.